# The Angular Material version (12.1.4) does not match the Angular CDK version (12.2.1). Please ensure the versions of these two packages exactly match

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-flex-layout

After installing [FlexLayout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) using this command

```
npm i -s @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk
```

Which obviously install `Angular CDK` as well, i'm getting the following warning

```
The Angular Material version (12.1.4) does not match the Angular CDK version (12.2.1).
Please ensure the versions of these two packages exactly match.
```

I used `ng update` command in order to update packages, also tried `ng add @angular/material`, but i'm still with the same versions.

How do I solve this?

**SOLUTION**

The commands `ng add @angular/material` & `ng add @angular/material@latest` works just fine, i checked the `package.json` file and noticed that i had

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.1"
    ... 
}
```

**it just needed an `ng serve` again.**

And one more thing, It seems like updating `Angular Material` doesn't really overrides the `styles.scss` file, but actually adds the same code again to the file, so i had to delete that too in order to get rid of the scss errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
ng add @angular/material@latest
```

or

```
ng add @angular/material@12.2.1
```

Comment: I'm very pleased to help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply match your angular cdk and material version, suppose your angular cdk version is 13.5.5 then your material version should be 13.5.5. Check your angular cdk version and then run command

ng add @angular/material@13.5.5

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on your terminal:

> npm install @angular/material@12.2.1 --force